# Hudson : warning MSB3245: Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework"

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, nunit, hudson, jobs

I'm working in a Virtual Machine as a Hudson Slave.
In the virtual machine, I add the path to the MSBuild I want to use :

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;
```

I added also the path to NUnit :

```
C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.7\bin\net-2.0;
```

And so, I can run the NUnit and MSBuild command lines in my VM.

But I get this error when my Hudson Job build my solution :

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework".
```

What should I fix in my VM or in Hudson? 
Thank you a lot!

**EDIT**

Here how the concerned file *.csproj references to the dll :

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.5.7.10213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=KKKKKKKKKK processorArchitecture=KKK">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>Dll\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue isn't the nunit-console.exe (or whatever the name).

The issue is that you cannot find nunit.framework.dll...as a reference in your project file (.csproj for C#).

Your unit-test project, you need to open it and find how/where the reference to the nunit.framwork.dll is wired.

Post the `.csproj` code if that is confusing.

EDIT:

```
<HintPath>Dll\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
```

The issue is that you need to "download" or copy or svn-export or svn-checkout or nuget-get that file.
And place it in the ***relative*** directory to your .csproj.

Because you have specified a HintPath, it will NOT find the one in this below directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.X.Y\bin\nunit.framework.dll
```

Basically, the `HintPath` says "I expect to find this file HERE", and your MSBUILD error says "I did not find it where the `HintPath` said it would be."

Comment: The project is very well coded. I built the solution according to each configuration (AnyCPU,Win32,x64) by Visual Studio 2008 graphically and it was generated successfuly. But when I build it remotely from Hudson, it fails to find the reference to that dll

Comment: Post your csproj code (open it in notepad). .. and post the section that has the nunit reference.

Comment: Could not get it to work without hint path
i just hardcoded default nunit install path:

`<HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>`

Comment: The Identity that runs the build-process.......must have access to that directory.  And giving the Identity that runs the build-process......permissions to "c:\program files\" (or similar) is not a best practice IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Under which user account does jenkins-slave.exe (or hudson slave) run on your VM node?

Paths to .NET dlls are registered in windows registries (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\VersionMinimum\AssemblyFoldersEx\MyAssemblies]@="AssemblyLocation"`).

By default jenkins runs jenkins-slave service under `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account (who probably doesn't have any AssemblyLocations registered on your system).

I filled my user acount login (under which the .csproj builds like a charm) details into jenkins -> nodes -> VM -> config and additionally set that same user account under which Windows runs the "jenkins slave" service (in VM's Windows Services -> jekins slave -> properties -> Log on -> This account: ...)

So it's working without specifying hint path in .csproj, because it is machine specific (my builds are running on multiple machines).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was in the build sequence.
Required libs were configured to build after the failed one.